# status 415 image upload DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

why i get 415 response when try to post by code?
having no problems with browser upload.

```
 class UploadImageView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
        queryset = Image.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ImageSerializer
     
 class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            fields = ('image', 'tags')
            model = Image
        def create(self, validated_data):
            image = Image.objects.create(**validated_data)
            return image
```

first try:
data = {'tags': 'testtag', 'image': '/home/Test/test.png'}

second:
data = {'tags': 'testtag', 'image': b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n......\x82'}

```
resp = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Also tried BytesIO object with the same result.

Response 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send post request as a binary file.

```
bin_files = {'image': open('/home/Test/test.png','rb')}
data = {'tags': 'testtag'}

resp = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```